# Which to use: 'from...to' or 'between..and'

Tags: prepositions

This sentence was in an editing exercise.

The reason is simply because sharks take **between** seven **to** twenty years to mature.

Suggested answer: 'to' should be changed to 'and'

Is it ok if 'between' is changed to 'from'?

..sharks take from seven to twenty years to mature. I know the 'from..to' sounds weird but grammatically is there anything wrong?

Comment: No, it isn't weird. Use either 'between... and' or 'from... to'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes to both.
Sharks take between seven and twenty years to mature.
Sharks take from seven to twenty years to mature.

The [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/between_1) gives the following examples for between:

> in the period of time that separates two days, years, events, etc.
>
> It's cheaper between 6 p.m. and 8 a.m.
> Don't eat between meals.
>   Children must attend school between the ages of 5 and 16.
> Many
>   changes took place between the two world wars.

[English4u](https://www.english-4u.de/en/grammar/prepositions-time.htm) has this to say on from-to

> FROM - TO
> We use from - to + beginning and end of a period
> Last
>   evening we watched TV from 5 to 8 o' clock.

If you google "from * to" (including the quotes) you will find countless more examples in everyday usage.